# problem in one to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Task.php**

```
public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
```

**Project.php**

```
 public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }
```

My Controller

```
public function store(Request $request,$id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'member_name' => 'required',
        'module' => 'required_without:file',
        'file' => 'required_without:module'
    ]);
    $project=Project::find($id);
    $task = new Task();
    if ($request->hasfile('file'))
    {
            $ext = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename=$request->module.".".$ext;
            $request->file->move(public_path() . '/members/', $filename);
            $task->file = $filename;
    }
    if($request->module)
    {
        $task->module=$request->module;
    }
    $task->member_name=$request->member_name;
    $project->tasks()->save($task);
    return redirect('tasks');
}
```

Now when i call save method it gives me the following error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::save()` I cant understand why this is happen. Please help me to solve this. I will be greatefull to you

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 $project->tasks()->save($task);
```

to this

```
$task->save();
```

Additionally project has many-to-one relation with tasks so the function name should be singular as many projects could be belong to only one task

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
```

Comment: Sorry. It was `$task`

Comment: 1364 Field 'project_id' doesn't have a default value.......it wil give this error

Comment: Let me check your relationship properly

Comment: because it is relationships ........btw problem is fixed now...i just mismatched with my relationships..

Comment: According to the relation the task has many projects. So there shouldn't be any project_id under tasks table. Instead there should be a task_id in the projects table

Comment: yes i already told you there is my mistake i mismatched this...and it is solved and thank you for your time